# compiling pdflatex from the terminal in vim

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, vim

A file I can compile in Texmaker won't compile after editing in Vim.  I am giving the error hw9problem1xplot can't be found.  This is from an includegraphics command.  However, the pdf image file is in the same folder as the tex file, and I was able to compile this file with the includegraphics from Texmaker.

What I have been doing is `:w` and `:!pdflatex %` but I am told that the pdf image file doesn't exist or it can't find it.  How can this be?  I can compile the file in Texmaker without an issue.

**So I found the problem, Vim is saving the file elsewhere and not where I pulled the file from.  So it is looking for the pdf in the wrong directory.  How can I change where Vim saves the file?**

What do I need to setup to correct this issue?

After vonbrand's a suggestion, I tried running `:!pdflatex -shell-escape %`.  Unfortunately, I received the same error message.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `hw9problem1xplot' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.86 ...degraphics[width = 3in]{hw9problem1xplot}}
```

I have tried hw9problem1xplot with and without .pdf too.

I commented out the figure with the with the includegraphics and it compiled without an issue.  I double checked the folder and the pdfs are present so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: There is the add-on `vim-latexsuite`, which you can install via `apt`.  (I don't use `vim` myself, however.)  Also you should be able to compile your file regardless of whether `vim` is visiting the file or not.

Comment: @jon I have the latex suite installed.  I just started trying out Vim with the Latex suite so I don't know how run that yet and why I am enquiring.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never used it myself; but see [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) for the manual, etc.

Comment: I can't find the /.vimrc file to edit that is mentioned in all the documents so the manual hasn't helped me.  I am on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You probably need to create the `.vimrc`; e.g., you could do `touch ~/.vimrc` to create an empty file in your home directory.  Afterwards, you can add whatever you like/need to it.  But *don't* put an rc-file in your rootd directory!  There is a big difference between `/.vimrc` and `~/.vimrc`!!  (The latter is a shortform for `/home/<USER>/`.)

Comment: If you run `pdflatex file.tex` it should work, or give some error messages. In my experience the "easy to use" LaTeX systems add all sorts of horrible macros that have to be unraveled to get readable source, perhaps you are tripping over one of those? See if an _unedited_ file can be processed on the command line. Look at the manual page for `pdflatex`, perhaps you need `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex` (careful, that means Unix commands are allowed to be run from the `.tex` source!).

Comment: @vonbrand I just tried running pdflatex with shell escape but that didn't do it work. Good suggestion though.

Comment: Try a (minimal) piece from the file made in TeXmaker, and see if pdflatex chokes. If still mystified, perhaps post a MWE here.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you get when running pdflatex?  Also, what does Vim status line tell you about the file encoding?  Could it be that the file was somehow converted and some invisible characters are messing up the compilation?

Comment: If you have LaTeX-suite installed, you should be able to type `\ll` in the normal mode in Vim, and the document should compile.  However, it pretty much does the same thing as `:w` followed by `:!pdflatex %`, so I doubt it will fix your problem.

Comment: A (maybe not-so-)stupid question: the graphic file doesn't have the *same* basename, differing from the LaTeX file only by the extension, does it?  If yes, *every second* compilation will fail...

Comment: @mbork the file is 211Homework9.tex and the graphics is hw9problem1xplot.pdf

Comment: Hm, it does not seem like this is a TeX question after all ,but rather a Vim question.  Anyway, can you find out where does Vim save the file?  How excatly are you openning the file in Vim at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim was saving to the home directory when I was working with a file in documents.

So I changed the the working directory to my documents by:

```
:cd %:p:h
```

Comment: you might like to put `set autochdir` in your `~/.vimrc` too :)

Comment: @cmhughes can you walk me through the steps of creating that file and setting it up?  I can't figure it out from the manual.

Comment: @cmhughes which room?